# Need help in optimising the MySql stored procedure

Tags: mysql

I have a stored procedure which is used to delete table entries. I have the input to the procedure as an array so that I can pass them as is for the delete queries [For ex: Use the IN clause to submit the array]. Even though the array items are integers, I had read that I need to pass them as string arrays. What is happening with this is, I'm not able to pass the array entries entirely to the Delete query and need to loop through them and submit individual entry to the Delete query. Could I get any suggestions/help to achieve this? Below mentioned is the procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Delete_Proc`(IN entity_id_array varchar(100), IN mgmt_module varchar(10))
BEGIN

    -- Declare variables to hold diagnostics area information
    DECLARE errCode CHAR(5) DEFAULT '00000';
    DECLARE msgTxt TEXT;
    DECLARE rowCount INT;
    DECLARE resVal TEXT;


    DECLARE _sRemainder TEXT; 
    DECLARE _Delimiter CHAR(1); 
    DECLARE _nPos INT DEFAULT 1;
    DECLARE _sStr VARCHAR(100); 
    DECLARE _entitId INT;


    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION

    GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1
        errCode = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, msgTxt = MESSAGE_TEXT;


    SET _sRemainder = entity_id_array; 

        WHILE CHAR_LENGTH(_sRemainder) > 0 AND _nPos > 0 DO 

            SET _nPos = INSTR(_sRemainder, ',');

            IF _nPos = 0 THEN 
                SET _sStr = _sRemainder; 
            ELSE 
                SET _sStr = LEFT(_sRemainder, _nPos - 1); 
            END IF;

            IF TRIM(_sStr) != '' THEN

                Set _entitId = CAST(_sStr AS UNSIGNED);

                        DELETE user_management, user_endpoint_association, user_group_association 
                                FROM user_management
                                    INNER JOIN
                                        user_endpoint_association ON user_endpoint_association.user_id = user_management.user_id
                                    INNER JOIN
                                        user_group_association ON user_group_association.user_id = user_management.user_id
                            WHERE
                                user_management.user_id = _entitId;

            END IF; 

            SET _sRemainder = SUBSTRING(_sRemainder, _nPos + 1); 
        END WHILE;



  -- Check whether the delete was successful
  IF errCode = '00000' THEN
    GET DIAGNOSTICS rowCount = ROW_COUNT;
    SET resVal = CONCAT('Delete succeeded, row count = ', rowCount);
  ELSE
    SET resVal = CONCAT('Delete failed, error = ', errCode,', message = ', msgTxt);
  END IF;
  -- Say what happened
  SELECT resVal;

END
```

=======================================================================

Here is the output of Explain Delete:

[image: Explain Delete Result]

=========================================================================

Here is the output after adding the indexes:

[image: After adding index]

Comment: Having a loop in a Stored Procedure is usually an indication that one needs to rethink the design.

Answer (score 1):

So, your problem is, that you want to give a string like `1,3,5,7` as parameter to the procedure to actually do a query like `delete from foo where id in (proc_parameter)`, right?

The problem with this is, that the query becomes this: `delete from foo where id in ('1,3,5,7')`. Then an implicit conversion from string to integer happens and the only entry that gets deleted is the one with id 1.

The most convenient solution would be, that the query with the replaced parameter wouldn't have those single-quotes. You can do this with prepared statements. The procedure would then look something like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_del(IN my_array VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN 
    SET @sql := CONCAT('DELETE FROM foo WHERE id IN (', my_array, ');');
    SELECT @sql AS the_fancy_query_I_will_execute; -- debugging, not needed ;)
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

and called with

```
CALL sp_del('1,3,5,7');
```

But that all being said, why don't you just solve this on application level instead? That's what I would do!

Comment: Thought it would be faster in performance if IN clause is used instead of looping through every entry

Comment: It usually is, yes. Is this not the case for you?

Comment: Certainly, hence was looking to replace loop with IN clause

Comment: Are your tables properly indexed? Post the result of `explain delete ...`

Comment: This could be worth another question, though, as this is a whole other topic.

Comment: I did not understand "Post the result of explain delete ...". Could you clarify?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain.html You execute your query with the keyword `explain` in front of it. Then mysql tells you, if and what indexes it would use, if it has to create a temporary table and several other things. And the result of `show create table <your_table_name>\G` would also be useful.

Comment: I have edited the main thread and posted the output

Comment: There is your performance problem. Type ALL means it's doing a full table scan. That's the worst of the worst. You have no index on the columns `user_endpoint_association.user_id` and `user_group_association.user_id`. Create an index on those and you'll probably be fine.

Comment: I have posted the result after adding the index

Comment: And do you still have performance problems?

Comment: No, not now. Indexing did the trick

Comment: When all your problems are solved, feel free to accept my answer :)